# Unable to parse Json with special character inside Apex

Tags: community, replace

I need to parse the below JSON in salesforce apex. In the message value, special character is not allowing to parse. Added image of JSON parser online.

Javascript replace wont work in apex

Ex: imagepath = imagepath.replace(/\/g, "\\") //wont work with this syntax

[image: JSON Parsed online]

Comment: This is not valid JSON at all. Are you very sure this is the raw data you're receiving? It's common for string representations to confuse the issue by, for example, hiding escape characters.

Comment: stackexchnage removed my special character in json. hence modified question now which includes image.

Comment: @DavidReed Also I tried the other solution mentioned here to use two \\ rather than one \ . Even the Json string with two \\ is invalid when tried to parse online.  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416529/json-parse-double-quotes-in-string-literal

Comment: Apex will correctly parse this directly and there is no need to try to remove the backslashes.

Comment: You need to show the apex code you are having difficulty with so we can understand your problem case. Please add it (use the code insert markup to ensure Stack Exchange doesn't mess with it - three back quotes to start then three back quotes to end).

Comment: I've linked this post to an existing question that I believe is the same problem. If you disagree, please [edit] your post and it can be reopened.